# How to using preg_replace() remove value duplicate from an URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a simple URL:

```
http://sample.com/?page=1&page=2
http://sample.com/?page=2&page=1
```

How to using preg_replace() to remove value duplicate (page)

This is the code:

```
$link = preg_replace("/\b(\w+)\s+\\1\b/i", "$1", $link );
```

But the result is wrong, how do I fix it so the result looks like:

```
http://sample.com/?page=1&page=2 => http://sample.com/?page=2
http://sample.com/?page=2&page=1 => http://sample.com/?page=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider recursing the subpattern instead of trying to use a backreference.

```
$link = 'http://sample.com/?page=1&page=2';
$link = preg_replace('/\b(\w+=\d+)&((?1))/', '$2', $link);
echo $link; //=> "http://sample.com/?page=2"
```

Using a backreference I suppose you could do:

```
$link = preg_replace('/\b(\w+=)\d+&(\1\d+)/', '$2', $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
\?.*?\K([^=]+)(?:=[^&]*)?&(.*)\1=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

With:

```
\2\1=\3
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/eN9cS2/2)

---

```
\?      (?# match ? literally)
.*?     (?# lazily match unnecessary params)
\K      (?# throw away everything to the left)
([^=]+) (?# capture 1+ non-= characters)
(?:     (?# start non-capturing group)
  =     (?# match = literally)
  [^&]* (?# match 0+ non-& characters)
)?      (?# end optional parameter value)
&       (?# match & literally)
(.*)    (?# capture optional inbetween junk)
\1     (?# a paramater that has already been seen in capture group 1)
=       (?# literally match =)
(.*?)   (?# lazily capture the newest value)
(?:     (?# begin non-capturing group)
  &     (?# literally match &)
 |      (?# OR)
  $     (?# match the end of the URL)
)       (?# end non-capturing group)
```